# Pivoting a table with duplicate entries in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Is there a way to pivot the User's Character Height and Weight Table table (A) with pandas to (B)? I have tried using unstack but it doesn't seem to work.

(A) User's Character Height and Weight Table

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|     USER_ID    Category    Height    Weight |
+---------------------------------------------+
|     USER 1      Green       172cm      69kg |
|     USER 2      Blue        169cm      61kg |
|     USER 1      Red         153cm      41kg |
|     USER 3      Green       172cm      59kg |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

(B)

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USER_ID Green Height_Green Weight_Green Blue Height_Blue Weight_Blue Red  Height_Red  Weight_Red |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USER 1    1      172.0        69.0        0       0.0       0.0       1      153.0        41.0   |
| USER 2    0        0.0         0.0        1     169.0      61.0       0        0.0         0.0   |            
| USER 3    1      172.0        59.0        0       0.0       0.0       0        0.0         0.0   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried using unstack but it doesn't seem to work. Because there are multiple same user ids, pivot_table will give me a ValueError, saying Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Is there a workaround for this problem?

```
df.groupby('USER_ID')['Category','Height', 'Weight'] \
      .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist(),
             columns=['Category','Height', 'Weight'])) \
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: one way is to group  by `category` and then concatenate (merge) the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to split the problem:

- first convert Height and Weight column to floating point values
- produce the Green, Blue and Red column by pivoting the dataframe with an auxilliary column
- produce the type_color column with `unstack`
- concatenate the above column and reindex to produce the final dataframe

Code could be:

```
# convert the values to float
for col in ['Height', 'Weight']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.slice(stop=-2).astype('float')

# First columns
tmp1 = df[['USER_ID', 'Category']].assign(val=1).pivot(
    'USER_ID', 'Category', 'val').fillna(0).astype(int)

# Other columns
tmp2 = df.set_index(['USER_ID', 'Category']).unstack().fillna(0)
tmp2.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in tmp2.columns]

# compute the expected column names
final_cols = [i for j in [[i] + ['_'.join((j,i)) for j in ('Height', 'Weight')]
              for i in ['Green', 'Blue', 'Red']] for i in j]

# finaly produce the result dataframe
resul = pd.concat([tmp1, tmp2], axis=1).reindex(columns=final_cols
                                                ).reset_index()
```

With your initial data it gives:

```
  USER_ID  Green  Height_Green  Weight_Green  Blue  Height_Blue  Weight_Blue  Red  Height_Red  Weight_Red
0  USER 1      1         172.0          69.0     0          0.0          0.0    1       153.0        41.0
1  USER 2      0           0.0           0.0     1        169.0         61.0    0         0.0         0.0
2  USER 3      1         172.0          59.0     0          0.0          0.0    0         0.0         0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify your end result; I am assuming you want those to be NaN or some type of value to indicate that those are empty instead of 0 since that might affect the next step in processing.

Additionally, I am not clear what you wish to achieve by having columns like 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red'. Since you wish to have unique values per user, I would assume you want a boolean array so you know if there is a meaningful value or not.

Assuming I understand correctly, here is the code to get what you need

```
d = {'USER_ID': ['USER 1', 'USER 2', 'USER 1', 'USER 3'],
     "Category": ['Green', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
     'Height': ['172cm', '169cm', '153cm', '172cm'],
     'Weight': ['69kg', '61kg', '41kg', '59kg']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.pivot(index='USER_ID', columns='Category')
```

You can look up on the documentation for pivot here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

These are a few steps as the original df is not ready for pivot.

1. to create dataframe

   ```
      df = pd.DataFrame({
      'UserID': ['USER 1', 'USER 2', 'USER 1', 'USER 3'],
      'Category':  ['Green', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
      'Height':  [1, 2, 3, 1],
      'Weight': [3.0, 2.0, 2.88, 1.33]
   })
   ```
2. Melt it (unpivot) to create a conform data format to be pivoted

   `df_m = df.melt(id_vars=['UserID','Category'])`
3. Create `is` + `color` so the pivot can show the color column

   ```
       df_add = df_m[df_m.duplicated(['UserID','Category'])].copy()
       df_add['variable'] = 'IS' + df_add['Category'] 
       df_add['value'] = 1
   ```
4. Final step is to create a pivot table from `df_m`.append(`df_add`)

   `pd.pivot_table(df_m.append(df_add),index=['UserID'],columns=['Category','variable'])`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `melt` and `pivot_table`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([('USER 1', 'Green', '172', '69'),('USER 2', 'Blue', '169', '61'),('USER 1', 'Red', '153', '41'),('USER 3', 'Green', '172', '59')], columns=['USER_ID','Category','Height','Weight'])

df['Color'] =  1 # For the color column

table = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['USER_ID','Category'], value_vars=['Height','Weight', 'Color'])

table['Cat_Var'] = table['Category'] + '_' + table['variable'] 

table = table.pivot_table(values=['value'], index=['USER_ID'],
                    columns=['Cat_Var'], aggfunc='max', fill_value=0)

print(table)
```

Result:

```
             value
Cat_Var Blue_Color Blue_Height Blue_Weight Green_Color Green_Height Green_Weight Red_Color Red_Height Red_Weight
USER_ID
USER 1           0           0           0           1          172           69         1        153         41
USER 2           1         169          61           0            0            0         0          0          0
USER 3           0           0           0           1          172           59         0          0          0
```